# How do I display an empty div tag with CSS?

Tags: html, css

How do I force this empty div tag to show? I have to add `&nbsp;` in the div for it to show. Is there a way to force it to display using only CSS?

```
<div class="bar bg-success" title="2015-07-23,5.0000" height="50%"></div>

.bar {
  background: green;
  width: 5px;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
```

I tried adding

```
.bar:after {
  content: " ";
}
```

but that didn't help.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cf0gprLn/ 
Bootply: http://www.bootply.com/TNjKAPiO7l

---

Please ignore all below answers saying to set the height in the CSS. The height has to be set dynamically. `&nbsp;` makes it display.

---

Sorry I realize I made a mistake with the height style. I'm not sure what I was thinking. However, it still doesn't work with:

```
<div class="bar bg-success" title="2015-07-23,5.0000" style="height: 50%;"></div>
```

---

I see it works in JSFiddle, but not Bootply. It's now a problem with Bootstrap. Since the question changed, I'll re-enter a different question. Updated BootPly with inline style: http://www.bootply.com/0ApACbxmwP

Comment: Try adding a CSS `height`.

Comment: @aug Height is specified as an attribute.

Comment: such mixing attributes and css may lead to problems (as one u had)

Comment: @Chloe `div` is not an element that actually recognizes what a `height` attribute is. Only some HTML elements do like `iframe` or `svg`. You can read more about [`<div>` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div).

Comment: @Chloe, did my answer solve your problem? I also updated my answer.

Comment: @Chloe I notice you edited your question to say _Please ignore all below answers saying to set the height in the CSS. The height has to be set dynamically. &nbsp; makes it display_. Sure that might work but that's a hack and shouldn't be encourage. Your real issue is you do not have a `height` and since it is a floating element with nothing inside, it simply shows what you configured -- an empty block with nothing but a width. You can set CSS heights dynamically.

Comment: @chloe changing the height attribute to a height css property, even if you still apply it in-line in your html rather than in your css file, will work: http://jsfiddle.net/70xovu32/ (changing the height attribute is the only thing i did).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work! :) You just have to add a `height` to it as well! :)

You can view the updated fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/cf0gprLn/1/

**EDIT**

I see that you added `height` to your HTML. The reason that is not working is because that is styling the whole div. The class on the other hand is kind of separate, and the height and width both need to be defined there. Its either all there, or in the HTML it self.

Comment: The height is specified as an attribute.

Comment: @Chloe, my Fiddle works, just add the height too the `.bar`, it seems to be working for me.

Comment: in same time i pushed height to css and it gave you your sollution. check answer below

Comment: @PawełSmołka what do you mean?

Comment: What I mean is in answer I have gave with full code to the answer.

`.bar {
  background: green;
  width: 5px;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.well { 
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
}


<div class="well">
  <div class="bar bg-success" title="2015-07-23,5.0000"></div>
</div>`

Comment: @PawełSmołka I do not see your point :( What are you trying to say?

Comment: @MichaelJones are you drunk? Check answers (not comments)

Comment: @PawelSmolka, what? I am reading answers, and there is nothing. What is your problem? Do you think I stole your answer? I posted mine 2 minutes before you.

Comment: Lol no, you just comment like you would be drunk. I even put all my answer to comments for you and you are still asking me what do I mean/what is my point. Just have no idea what answer you want to recieve. Ofcourse your answer is good answer, hmm mby you ask for "in same time i pushed height to css and it gave you your sollution. check answer below" - I just mean in same time both of us gave him correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.bar {
  background: green;
  width: 5px;
  height: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}
.well { 
    position: relative;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid gray; 
}
```

And your HTML

```
<div class="well">
  <div class="bar bg-success" title="2015-07-23,5.0000"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Pretty close.  You just need a height for the bar class.

Try this,

```
.bar {
  background-color: green;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: he wanted 50% not 100%

Answer (score -1):

I would also add to others' answers that your "after" trick didn't work because that places content AFTER what is enclosed in your div tag. Try it with a non-blank character, and you should see that is the case.

Comment: I tried adding `content: " ";` to the `.bar` itself, but that did not work. I also tried `.bar:before` and that didn't work either.

Comment: this answer is not really accurate. `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements are in the shadow dom (detached from the regular dom) but are treated (and represented) as children of the element, and their content is inserted at the end of the element's DOM content (but still inside the element).